# Taking Mysql database backup in Linux showing java.io.IOException:

Tags: java, mysql, linux

While using the following code to take a Mysql database backup

```
String shellCommand = "mysqldump --user" + dbUser + " --password="
                       + dbPass + " --databases" + dbName
                       +" |gzip - 9 > backup.sql.gz";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c",shellCommand});
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
```

I am getting the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program 
"/bin/bash": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Why? You can schedule backups directly from within MySQL. There's no need to write Java code for this task.

Comment: What I want to do is take  backup in folder /public_html/backup/backup_timestamp.sql.gz  then after taking backup a send mail function should attach this  file and email it.

Comment: @EJP how to do with mysql

Comment: With the MySQL Workbench. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X your code didn't throw an exception bud didn't do anything either. After examining contents of Process.getErrorStream() it seems that the command couldn't find mysqldump. Passing full path to mysqldump (e.g. output of `locate mysqldump`) worked (there were also some errors in mysqldump syntax in your code). Here's code that works (at least on OS X):

```
String shellCommand = "/usr/local/bin/mysqldump --user=" + dbUser + " --password="
        + dbPass + " --databases " + dbName
        +" |gzip -9 > backup.sql.gz";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c",shellCommand});
int exitValue = process.waitFor();
```

Please note that this code is potentially vulnerable to a dangerous command injection security vulnerability. If the parameters (username, password and database name) are under control of application user, malicious user might manipulate parameters to execute commands on the operating system (for example by passing `dbname | rm -rf / |` as database name). You must make sure that these parameters are not under control of application user or take other measures to prevent the vulnerability (OS command escaping or executing mysqldump and then gzip directly to Runtime.exec as separate processes and connecting input stream of the first one to output stream of the second one in the application).